# gltf exported from blender with metallic texture and no roughness texture is loaded into three.js with roughness texture matching metallic texture

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

If the metallic texture is being reused (same UUID) as the roughness texture and I don't need the roughness texture, would it be more performant to set the roughnessMap as null?

I don't understand why the metallic texture is being reused so an explanation of that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.metalnessMap` uses [the blue channel](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.metalnessMap) while the `.roughnessMap` uses the [green channel](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.roughnessMap) of the same texture. This is done to save filesize and memory, since using a single RGB texture for multiple purposes is more cost-effective than using separate RGB textures.

Ambient occlusion uses [the red channel](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.aoMap) of the assigned texture, so you could potentially have three separate maps for the price of one!